# How to increase the width of subplots in Basemap?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am having a problem with subplots when using Basemap. I am plotting relative humidity (RH) measured in six pressure levels by a satellite. In the first image (Figure 1) I have plotted RH measured over the satellite's entire trajectory (encircling the globe). Each subplot corresponds to one pressure level. This figure is fine. However, to study a certain measured event (here: the tropical cyclone seen east of Madagascar) I want to zoom in on the figure. Zooming in (in terms of limiting the latitudinal and longitudinal range) also seems to work fine (Figure 2).

BUT, in Figure 2 the subplots don't make use of the entire figure space at their disposal. I imagine that all components seen in Figure 2 (i.e., the map and measured RH) would be enlarged if the subplots made use of the entire width of the figure. In other words, I want my subplots in Figure 2 to be just as wide as the subplots in Figure 1. Please, how can I do this?

Here is my code:

*First I load my file and my variables*

*Then comes the plotting:*

```
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib import gridspec


# Generate variables
lat_use = np.arange(29.5, 30.5, 1)
lon_use = np.arange(179.5, 180.5, 1) 
RH = np.random.random((60, 360, 6))

plt.subplot(611) 
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=180, llcrnrlat=-29.5, urcrnrlat=29.5, resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines(color='k')
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lon_use,lat_use)
x, y = m(lons,lats)
m.contourf(x, y, RH[:,:,5], cmap='RdYlBu')
plt.xlim(-179.5, 179.5)
plt.xticks([-180, -120, -60, 0, 60, 120, 180], ['180W', '120W', '60W', '0E', '60E', '120E', '180E'], fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-29.5, 29.5)
plt.yticks([-30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30], ['30S', '20S', '10S', '0', '10N', '20N', '30N'], fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('6th')
plt.title('RH in 6 levels')
#plt.show()

plt.subplot(612)
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=180, llcrnrlat=-29.5, urcrnrlat=29.5, resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines(color='k')
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lon_use,lat_use)
x, y = m(lons,lats)
m.contourf(x, y, RH[:,:,4], cmap='RdYlBu')
plt.xlim(-179.5, 179.5)
plt.xticks([-180, -120, -60, 0, 60, 120, 180], ['180W', '120W', '60W', '0E', '60E', '120E', '180E'], fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-29.5, 29.5)
plt.yticks([-30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30], ['30S', '20S', '10S', '0', '10N', '20N', '30N'], fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('5th')
#plt.show()

plt.subplot(613)
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=180,     llcrnrlat=-29.5, urcrnrlat=29.5, resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines(color='k')
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lon_use,lat_use)
x, y = m(lons,lats)
m.contourf(x, y, RH[:,:,3], cmap='RdYlBu')
plt.xlim(-179.5, 179.5)
plt.xticks([-180, -120, -60, 0, 60, 120, 180], ['180W', '120W', '60W', '0E', '60E', '120E', '180E'], fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-29.5, 29.5)
plt.yticks([-30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30], ['30S', '20S', '10S', '0', '10N', '20N', '30N'], fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('4th')
#plt.show()

plt.subplot(614)
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=180,     llcrnrlat=-29.5, urcrnrlat=29.5, resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines(color='k')
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lon_use,lat_use)
x, y = m(lons,lats)
m.contourf(x, y, RH[:,:,2], cmap='RdYlBu')
plt.xlim(-179.5, 179.5)
plt.xticks([-180, -120, -60, 0, 60, 120, 180], ['180W', '120W', '60W', '0E', '60E', '120E', '180E'], fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-29.5, 29.5)
plt.yticks([-30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30], ['30S', '20S', '10S', '0', '10N', '20N', '30N'], fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('3rd')
#plt.show()

plt.subplot(615)
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=180,             llcrnrlat=-29.5, urcrnrlat=29.5, resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines(color='k')
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lon_use,lat_use)
x, y = m(lons,lats)
m.contourf(x, y, RH[:,:,1], cmap='RdYlBu')
plt.xlim(-179.5, 179.5)
plt.xticks([-180, -120, -60, 0, 60, 120, 180], ['180W', '120W', '60W', '0E', '60E', '120E', '180E'], fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-29.5, 29.5)
plt.yticks([-30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30], ['30S', '20S', '10S', '0', '10N', '20N', '30N'], fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('2nd') 
#plt.show()

plt.subplot(616)
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=180, llcrnrlat=-29.5, urcrnrlat=29.5, resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines(color='k')
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lon_use,lat_use)
x, y = m(lons,lats)
m.contourf(x, y, RH[:,:,0], cmap='RdYlBu')
plt.xlim(-179.5, 179.5)
plt.xticks([-180, -120, -60, 0, 60, 120, 180], ['180W', '120W', '60W', '0E', '60E', '120E', '180E'], fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-29.5, 29.5)
plt.yticks([-30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30], ['30S', '20S', '10S', '0', '10N', '20N', '30N'], fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('1st') 

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1, right=0.8, top=0.9)
cax = plt.axes([0.85, 0.1, 0.075, 0.8])
plt.colorbar(cax=cax, label='RH [%]')
plt.show()

# Plot RH in the six vertical levels with Basemap:
# But only in the interval 30E-70E and 0S-30S
# Define limits
lon_beg = 220
lon_end = 261
lat_beg = 30
lat_end = 60
lons_lim = lons[lat_beg:lat_end,lon_beg:lon_end]
lats_lim = lats[lat_beg:lat_end,lon_beg:lon_end]

plt.subplot(611) 
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', llcrnrlon=40, urcrnrlon=80, llcrnrlat=-29.5, urcrnrlat=0.5, resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines(color='k')
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lon_use,lat_use)
x, y = m(lons_lim,lats_lim)
m.contourf(x, y, RH[lat_beg:lat_end,lon_beg:lon_end,5], cmap='RdYlBu')
plt.xlim(40.5, 80.5)
plt.xticks([40, 50, 60, 70, 80], ['40E', '50E', '60E', '70E', '80E'], fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-29.5, 0.5)
plt.yticks([-30, -20, -10, 0], ['30S', '20S', '10S', '0'], fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('6th') 
plt.title('RH in 6 levels: Zoomed In') 
#plt.show()

plt.subplot(612)
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', llcrnrlon=40, urcrnrlon=80, llcrnrlat=-29.5, urcrnrlat=0.5, resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines(color='k')
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lon_use,lat_use)
x, y = m(lons_lim,lats_lim)
m.contourf(x, y, RH[lat_beg:lat_end,lon_beg:lon_end,4], cmap='RdYlBu')
plt.xlim(40.5, 80.5)
plt.xticks([40, 50, 60, 70, 80], ['40E', '50E', '60E', '70E', '80E'], fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-29.5, 0.5)
plt.yticks([-30, -20, -10, 0], ['30S', '20S', '10S', '0'], fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('5th') 
#plt.show()

plt.subplot(613)
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', llcrnrlon=40, urcrnrlon=80, llcrnrlat=-29.5, urcrnrlat=0.5, resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines(color='k')
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lon_use,lat_use)
x, y = m(lons_lim,lats_lim)
m.contourf(x, y, RH[lat_beg:lat_end,lon_beg:lon_end,3], cmap='RdYlBu')
plt.xlim(40.5, 80.5)
plt.xticks([40, 50, 60, 70, 80], ['40E', '50E', '60E', '70E', '80E'], fontsize=10)
plt.yticks([-30, -20, -10, 0], ['30S', '20S', '10S', '0'], fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('4th')
#plt.show()

plt.subplot(614)
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', llcrnrlon=40, urcrnrlon=80, llcrnrlat=-29.5, urcrnrlat=0.5, resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines(color='k')
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lon_use,lat_use)
x, y = m(lons_lim,lats_lim)
m.contourf(x, y, RH[lat_beg:lat_end,lon_beg:lon_end,2], cmap='RdYlBu')
plt.xlim(40.5, 80.5)
plt.xticks([40, 50, 60, 70, 80], ['40E', '50E', '60E', '70E', '80E'], fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-29.5, 0.5)
plt.yticks([-30, -20, -10, 0], ['30S', '20S', '10S', '0'], fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('3rd') 
#plt.show()

plt.subplot(615)
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', llcrnrlon=40, urcrnrlon=80, llcrnrlat=-29.5, urcrnrlat=0.5, resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines(color='k')
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lon_use,lat_use)
x, y = m(lons_lim,lats_lim)
m.contourf(x, y, RH[lat_beg:lat_end,lon_beg:lon_end,1], cmap='RdYlBu')
plt.xlim(40.5, 80.5)
plt.xticks([40, 50, 60, 70, 80], ['40E', '50E', '60E', '70E', '80E'], fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-29.5, 0.5)
plt.yticks([-30, -20, -10, 0], ['30S', '20S', '10S', '0'], fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('2nd')
#plt.show()

plt.subplot(616)
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', llcrnrlon=40, urcrnrlon=80, llcrnrlat=-29.5, urcrnrlat=0.5, resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines(color='k')
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lon_use,lat_use)
x, y = m(lons_lim,lats_lim)
m.contourf(x, y, RH[lat_beg:lat_end,lon_beg:lon_end,0], cmap='RdYlBu')
plt.xlim(40.5, 80.5)
plt.xticks([40, 50, 60, 70, 80], ['40E', '50E', '60E', '70E', '80E'], fontsize=10)
plt.ylim(-29.5, 0.5)
plt.yticks([-30, -20, -10, 0], ['30S', '20S', '10S', '0'], fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('1st')

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1, right=0.8, top=0.9)
cax = plt.axes([0.85, 0.1, 0.075, 0.8])
plt.colorbar(cax=cax, label='RH [%]')
plt.show()
```

Figure 1. RH plotted in six pressure levels (six subplots).

[image]

Figure 2. Basically Figure 1 zoomed in. RH plotted in six pressure levels (six subplots) zoomed in around Madagascar. The problem is that in this figure, the subplots don't make use of the entire width of the figure. They are supposed to have the same width as the subplots in Figure 1.

[image]

Comment: This is pretty hard to debug without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Presumably this is an aspect ratio issue: To get the subplots in your second image to be the full width, you would need to either extend the range on the x axis, reduce the range on the y axis, or change the aspect ratio of the `Axes`, although I'm not sure the latter option is a good idea on a map projection.

Comment: @DavidG I have now tried to generate the variables latitude, longitude and RH now (see the modified code).

Comment: @tom I think you are right, but how can I then (supposedley) extend the range of the x axis or (perhaps) reduce the range of the y axis?

Comment: you are setting them explicitly with `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim`, so just change what you have there

Comment: @tom but I thought that I with plt.xlim set the range of (here: longitudinal) values I want to be accounted for. That is not my problem for the correct range is accounted for. What I want to do is to widen the frame of the subplot itself to the left and right edges of the figure. But I still only want to see longitudes between 40E and 80E.

Comment: Yes, that's the issue I mentioned earlier. To get the subplot to stretch to that shape, you either need to change the longitudes you are plotting over, or change the aspect ratio. I doubt that changing the aspect ratio of a map projection is a good idea. So you are left with either changing the limits of your plot, or accepting the shape of the plots you have. A final option I guess would be to make the subplots (and hence the figure) physically taller

Comment: @tom I see. Thank you for explaining! Then I'm afraid I have to make due with the figure I've got.